# Use whenever gem to setup a cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I want to setup a `cron job` to delete screenshots which are older than two minutes and the cron job to run every two minutes.

Contents of  **schedule.rb file**

```
every 2.minutes do
  runner 'screenshot.delete_old', output: {error: "#{path}/log/error.log", standard: "#{path}/log/cron.log"}
end
```

Contents of Model Screenshot.rb file

```
def self.delete_old
       # @old_screenshots = Screenshot.where('Screenshot.created_at < ?', Time.now)
        #@old_screenshots.delete_all
        #@screenshot.delete_old
        #Screenshot.delete
        screenshot_ids = screenshot.find(:all, :conditions =>            ["created_at ", 2.minutes.ago])
        if screenshot_ids.size > 0
             screenshot.destroy(screenshot_ids)
             puts "#{screenshot_ids.size} screenshots have been deleted!"
        end
    end
```

I updated the crontab file and ran the rails server expecting the screeshots to be deleted. But it is not working. Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in Ruby should have capital first letter, maybe you should try:

```
every 2.minutes do
  runner 'Screenshot.delete_old', output: {error: "#{path}/log/error.log", standard: "#{path}/log/cron.log"}
end
```

and your model:

```
def self.delete_old
  screenshot_ids = Screenshot.where('created_at < ?', 2.minutes.ago))
  if screenshot_ids.size > 0
    Screenshot.destroy(screenshot_ids)
    puts "#{screenshot_ids.size} screenshots have been deleted!"
  end
end
```

Comment: I had delete semicolon from sql request, try again. And, please, try to run this code from console to see what's happening.

Error log will be helpful